# How does changing Pandas cell values affect memory?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns (col_a and col_b) and every value in the dataframe is an extremely long string.

I now want to make modifications to save memory.

1) dropping or deleting columns

```
df.drop(columns = [col_a], axis = 1)
del df[col_a]
```

The above to methods are equivalent. Do they both free up memory if an entire column is dropped or deleted?

2) What if I replace everything in col_b with np.nan or integers?

```
#original dataframe
df[col_b] = 'a'*100000000000000 # really long string

# change col_b's values in place
df[col_b] = 1 or df[col_b] = np.nan
```

Does this free up memory? Does pointing to np.nan take up less memory than an integer/float/string?

Comment: dropna and del are completely different. dropna drops rows/columns that have NaN values, del on the other hand deletes the column.

Comment: "the above methods are equivalent" No, they are not. One drops *rows* which are `NaN`, and *does not work in-place*, and the other simply in-place deletes a column

Comment: revised. I meant to write drop(cols, axis = 1), not dropna

Comment: `pandas` uses `object` dtype for strings (check `dtypes`).  That means that your long strings are stored independently in Python memory, and the dataframe just contains references to those strings.  If nothing else references the strings, they should be garbage collected once the dataframe no longer references them  So changing the column values or deleting the column should have a similar effect, at least with respect to the strings memory.